# Spark- how to count names by first character of the name from spark registered table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run below piece of spark code on pyspark and getting error. Could you please help me to understand what is missing?

```
p1 = pd.DataFrame(final_data,columns = ['Year','Name','Sex','Count'])      
h1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(p1)         
h1.registerTempTable('namesdb')             
sqlContext.sql("select SUBSTR(Name, 1, 1) as char1, count(Name) FROM namesdb group by char1 order by char1 ASC").toPandas()
```

But I am getting below error :

```
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'char1' given input columns: [Year, Name, Sex, Count];
```

Here are the sample records for final_data

```
final_data[:2]        

[[1880, 'Mary', 'F', '7065'],      
 [1880, 'Anna', 'F', '2604']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you cannot use the assigned column name 'as char1' in the group by clause, but you can just repeat the function in your group by clause like this:

```
select SUBSTR(Name, 1, 1) as char1, count(Name) FROM namesdb group by SUBSTR(NAME,1,1) order by char1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below. [Here](http://dinesql.blogspot.in/2014/01/why-column-aliases-are-not-recognized.html) is the detail how alias work in SQL Group By.

```
df1 = sqlContext.sql("select char1, count(Name) from (select *,SUBSTR(Name, 1, 1) char1 FROM namesdb) group by char1 order by char1 ASC")
df1.show()
```